# Несколько перенаправлений

Tags: php, редирект, header

Есть две страницы: index.php и news.php, на первой сначала идет проверка на существование в сессии логина и пароля пользователя (если он есть - идет редирект на страницу news.php, иначе остаётесь на этой странице и заполняете форму авторизации, которая и сохраняет логин и пароль в сессию), а на другой странице тоже хотелось бы иметь редирект на index.php (если кто-то попытается зайти напрямую). Но как только ставлю проверку сессии и header("Location: /index.php") в news.php, начинает ругаться.

Вопрос: как реализовать редирект с одной страницы на другую и в обратную сторону?

Comment: _"начинает ругаться"_ как именно?

Comment: Как и всегда, когда используешь несколько разных header(), т.е. "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ..."

Comment: По всей видимости, до вывода заголовка уже отрендерился контент или его часть. Но вызова `header()` не должно быть html тэгов и прочей нечисти

Comment: В начале файла `news.php` добавить условие на проверку сессии. Если сессия не существует то сделать редирект на `header("Location: /index.php"); exit;`